# Sprites won't move in cocos2d for android

Tags: android, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-android

I am having issues with cocos2d for Android. I have tried multiple methods but can't seem to get the sprite to move across the screen. Both pictures show up, but the computer sprite does not move. There are no errors that appear while running the code, but nothing happens besides the two pictures showing up with no movement.

```
    package com.example.minigameapp;

import java.util.Random;

import org.cocos2d.actions.instant.CCCallFuncN;
import org.cocos2d.actions.interval.CCMoveTo;
import org.cocos2d.actions.interval.CCSequence;
import org.cocos2d.layers.CCColorLayer;
import org.cocos2d.layers.CCScene;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCDirector;
import org.cocos2d.nodes.CCSprite;
import org.cocos2d.types.CGPoint;
import org.cocos2d.types.CGSize;
import org.cocos2d.types.ccColor4B;


import android.util.Log;

public class GameLayer extends CCColorLayer{
    CCSprite _player;
    CCSprite _computer;
    public static CCScene scene()
    {
        CCScene scene = CCScene.node();
        CCColorLayer layer = new GameLayer(ccColor4B.ccc4(255, 255, 255, 255));

        scene.addChild(layer);

        return scene;
    }

    protected GameLayer(ccColor4B color)
    {
        super(color);
        this.setIsTouchEnabled(true);
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();

        _player = CCSprite.sprite("race_car2.png");
        _computer = CCSprite.sprite("race_car.png");
        _player.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(_player.getContentSize().width / 2.0f, winSize.height / 2.0f));
        _computer.setPosition(CGPoint.ccp(_computer.getContentSize().width / 2.0f,winSize.height / 2.0f + _player.getContentSize().height*3));


        addChild(_player);
        addChild(_computer);
        this.schedule("moveComputer",1.0f);
    }
    public void moveComputer(){
        CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector().displaySize();
        float finalX=winSize.width;

        // Determine speed of the target
        Random rand = new Random();
        int minDuration = 2;
        int maxDuration = 15;
        int rangeDuration = maxDuration - minDuration;
        //int actualDuration = rand.nextInt(rangeDuration) + minDuration;
        int actualDuration=1;

        Log.d("GameLayer","Set Action");
        //CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(actualDuration, CGPoint.ccp(-computer.getContentSize().width / 2.0f, finalX));
        //CCCallFuncN actionMoveDone = CCCallFuncN.action(this, "spriteMoveFinished");
        //CCSequence actions = CCSequence.actions(actionMove, actionMoveDone);
        //computer.runAction(actions);
        CGPoint point = CGPoint.ccp(finalX,winSize.height / 2.0f + _player.getContentSize().height*3);
        CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(10, point);
        _computer.runAction(actionMove);
        Log.d("GameLayer", "Start Moving");
    }

    public void spriteMoveFinished(Object sender)
    {
        Log.d("GameLayer", "Finished Moving");
        //CCSprite sprite = (CCSprite)sender;
        //this.removeChild(sprite, true);
        this.removeChild(_computer, true);
        Log.d("GameLayer", "Remove Sprite");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have fixed the position of CGPoint

```
CGPoint point = CGPoint.ccp(finalX,winSize.height / 2.0f + _player.getContentSize().height*3);
        CCMoveTo actionMove = CCMoveTo.action(10, point);
```

You have to change the CGPoint values also in every schedule.

Your scheduled method running, but CG point value same every time method called and you have used the CCMoveTo which move the sprite to particular location on screen. So sprite is already in the postion where you want to move so that appear still(Not moved).

Change the CGPoint value every time scheduled method called...

you can check the difference by replacing CGPoint values as

```
CGPoint point = CGPoint.ccp(finalX+(100*Math.random()),winSize.height / 2.0f + player.getContentSize().height*3+(100*Math.random()));
```

Answer (score 0):

One small mistake i.e, in side `moveComputer()` you didnt pass `argumets.pass` arguments like below then your object will move

```
public void moveComputer(float dt)
{
  //
}
```